# How to force debug player not to launch a debug window, but silently output a message

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to test a very cpu intensive swf file in firefox browser. However the problem is whenever an unhandled error is encountered, it shows up debug window. I am trying to handle each and every error,but it becomes very difficult because at each error, the browser hangs up completely. And i have to restart. 
So, is there any good way, eg. through compiler etc, where i can tell debug player, not to show in a window, and halt the process, but just some other way to show output ?

I use general try..catch block. But still many a times, the window pops up. Seems like, try..catch block does not work in every case.

Here is a simple example : The code, lists all files in a directory, into a list component. When clicked, the selected file, must load. So, there is no problem with swf or picture files ( jpg, png etc). But say, i click upon a "FLA" which obviously should not load. The error window pops up unpredictably : Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

```
var loader:Loader =new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,updateInfo);

function fileList_Lst_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    doLoad();
}

function doLoad(e:MouseEvent=null):void {

    try
    {
    loader.load(new URLRequest(fileList_Lst.selectedItem.label));
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {
        trace(e.toString());
    }

    //infoBox.text="Loading starts...";


}

function updateInfo(e:ProgressEvent):void {

    trace("Loading: "+String(Math.floor(e.bytesLoaded/1024))+" KB of "+String(Math.floor(e.bytesTotal/1024))+" KB.");

}

function loadingError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {

     trace("There has been an error loading the image.");

         }


function doneLoad(e:Event):void {

    try
    {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,updateInfo);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
        displayView_Mc.addChild(loader);
    }
    catch(e:*)
    {
        trace("error loading!");
    }

  }
```

Comment: nice Question, let me try!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **UncaughtErrorEvent** in the root of your app.
This will catch all uncaught errors inside the app 
PS: you need to use flash player +10.x.x

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html#propertySummary

**SAMPLE App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
                       applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;

            private function applicationCompleteHandler():void
            {
                loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener( UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);
            }

            private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
            {
                // use prevent default and stopPropagation to prevent the Flash debug window appear
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                if (event.error is Error)
                {
                    var error:Error = event.error as Error;
                    // do something with the error
                }
                else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)
                {
                    var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
                    // do something with the error
                }
                else
                {
                    // a non-Error, non-ErrorEvent type was thrown and uncaught
                }
            }

            private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                throw new Error("Gak!");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="Cause Error" click="clickHandler(event);"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```